# How can I transform a pandas dataframe into a dictionary without the column headers?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, flatten

My current df:

---

```
   header1    header2  
   Siam       Thailand      
   Indonesie  Indonesia       
   Arabie     Yemen       
   Ceylon     Sri Lanka
```

So the headers of my df are 'header1' and 'header2'. The values are everything under these two headers.

I would like to transform this df into a flat dictionary, where the dictionary keys are the values of header1 and the dictionary values are the values of header2, like so:

**Desired output:**

```
{'Siam': 'Thailand', 'Indonesië': 'Indonesia', 'Arabië': 'Yemen', 'Ceylon': 'Sri Lanka'}
```

**Current output:**

```
{'header2':{'Siam': 'Thailand', 'Indonesie': 'Indonesia', 'Arabie': 'Yemen', 'Ceylon': 'Sri Lanka'}}
```

**My code:**

```
df.to_dict()
```

Comment: You could do: `result = dict(zip(df.header1, df.header2))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just:

```
{a:b for a,b in zip(df['header1'], df['header2'])}
```

or if you insist on `pandas` solution:

```
df.set_index('header1')['header2'].to_dict()
```

Output:

```
{'Siam': 'Thailand',
 'Indonesie': 'Indonesia',
 'Arabie': 'Yemen',
 'Ceylon': 'Sri Lanka'}
```